# How can I accurately calculate the robot configuration for a desired cartesian position, given manfuacturing discrepancies?

Tags: inverse-kinematics, industrial-robot, fanuc, cartesian

This is a question I have wrestled with for a while now and would appreciate any advice. I am writing an application which allows programming of different 6DOF industrial robotic arms. The output of the program will be a series of points defined in Cartesian space.

For some robot brands, I need to explicitly define the configuration of the robot. For example, for Fanuc systems, I need to specify a string like:
`CONFIG : 'F U T, 0, 0, 0'`.

This string explicitly defines the joint configuration for a given point, i.e. things like whether the elbow is up/down, wrist flipped and so on. There is a useful website here: https://www.onerobotics.com/posts/2013/the-perils-of-six-axis-robots/. The last digit of the 0, 0, **0**, string defines the range of solutions for axis 6.

Other robot brands offer other methods of defining the configuration, but it is all pretty similar. The problem I have is that - I need to perform inverse kinematics in order to calculate the configuration, and to perform inverse kinematics I need to input certain kinematic parameters.

Let's say I use the datasheet of a robotic system, and I use the theoretical kinematic parameters. Let's say I move my robot to point (X100, Y100, Z100), and my theoretical inverse kinematic solution generates an axis 6 solution of 179.9 degrees.

With a Fanuc system, I would generate a configuration string of `'F U T, 0, 0, 0'`.

Let's say due to manufacturing tolerances, the actual robot I am using has slightly different kinematic parameters and it needs an axis 6 solution of 180.1 degrees when moving to the same point. This solution would actually require a config string of `'F U T, 0, 0, 1'` to reach. If I send the `'F U T, 0, 0, 0'` string, the system would actually try to solve for an axis 6 within the range of -180 to +180, meaning that the closest solution would be an axis 6 value of -179.9.

This would result in axis 6 spinning nearly 360 degrees and crashing. How can I solve this problem? I appreciate any advice you can give me, thank you.